# Pandas: `or` operation on NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns such that each can have a value of `NaN`.
I'd like to populate a 4th column based on these 3, such that an `or` operation is applied on the columns: if the 1st is not `NaN`, take its value, else check the 2nd, etc.
Since a `NaN` value is not a `False`, the `or` operator cannot be used as-is.
Here is the code I came with, but it's not very Pythonic or Pandas-ic. Is there a built-in function that does it? or, if you have any other suggestions?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.NaN
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [nan, 1, nan], "b": [2, nan, nan], "c": [nan, nan, 3]})
#   a   b   c
# 0 NaN 2.0 NaN
# 1 1.0 NaN NaN
# 2 NaN NaN 3.0

nan_to_false = lambda val: False if pd.isna(val) else val

df["a_or_b_or_c"] = df.apply(lambda row: nan_to_false(row["a"]) or nan_to_false(row["b"]) or nan_to_false(row["c"]), axis=1)
# 0    2.0
# 1    1.0
# 2    3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is back filling missing values and then selecting first column:

```
df["all columns"] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

If need filter columns names:

```
df["a_or_b_or_c"] = df[['a','b','c']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: What if the first value is 0?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - then no repalced.

Comment: well, precisely. Then it is taken as the value, but that is not what the OP wants. So, use `df.iat[0,0] = 0` and test your solution's output against the OP's

Comment: @jezrael, This is working for me df.bfill(axis=1) , then why do we need iloc[:, 0]

Comment: @hackwithharsha - because need select first column, another columns are in ouput not necessary.

Comment: @jezrael no, we need to take *the logical `or` across the row*. So, for example, `0 or  1 or 4` will result in `1`, `0 or 0 or 4` will be `4`, `4 or 1 or 1` will be 4

Comment: @jezrael Got it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Understand. I think OP need replace NaN by a,b,c so this should working well if only one non NaN value per row. If multiple non NaNs the is values prioritized, high is `a`, then `b` and last `c`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that only one non-missing value on a line. You can try this trick

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.NaN
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [nan, 1, nan], "b": [2, nan, nan], "c": [nan, nan, 3]})

fn = lambda x: np.max(x)
df["a_or_b_or_c"] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].apply(fn, axis=1)

#
     a    b    c  a_or_b_or_c
0  NaN  2.0  NaN          2.0
1  1.0  NaN  NaN          1.0
2  NaN  NaN  3.0          3.0
```

Comment: Also,  `fn = lambda x: np.max(x)` can just be `np.max`... i.e. `apply(np.max)`, *but you shouldn't `.apply` a vectorized function*. *Just use the vectorized method to begin with*